# How to patch the value of multiselect dropdown (primeng component) in a reactive form?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am using primeng components in the template.
I have the option to edit the form, which displays the existing field values. I am not able to patch the value of multiselect dropdown.

```
excludeDays = [      
    {label: 'Mon', value: 1},
    {label: 'Tue', value: 2},
    {label: 'Wed', value: 3},
    {label: 'Thu', value: 4},
    {label: 'Fri', value: 5},
    {label: 'Sat', value: 6},
    {label: 'Sun', value: 7},
  ]
```

I have my backend data coming in as a string and then I am converting it into array of number like

```
[1,2] or[2,3,4]
```

Now after I press the edit button I want the values of the dropdown to be selected as above excludeDays values are there.

```
<div class="col-12" style="width: auto;" >
      <p-multiSelect [options]="excludeDays" optionLabel="label" defaultLabel="Select day" formControlName="excludeDays"></p-multiSelect> 
</div>
```

I am using

```
this.form.patchValue({
... : ....
excludeDays: converted array of (excludeDays) to number array
})
```

This is the console output of the excludeDays array after converting it into number array
[image: excludeArray]

Comment: All the answers below are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting data from the backend , create an array of objects using the original array, then set those values to the patchValue method.

```
const excludeDays = [1,2].map(id=>this.excludeDays.find(day=>day.value === id));

this.form.patchValue({
excludeDays: excludeDays
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Prime NG multiselect (**p-multiselect**) expects the same data type for **ngModel** property as that of **options** property.

That means, if your **options** are an array of **string** (string[]) then you can have ngModel to be an **array of string** as well. But if your options are an array of **objects**, then options will have to be array of **object** (object must be of same type).

So for example, you have this array to bind to p-multiselect

```
excludeDays = [      
{label: 'Mon', value: 1},
{label: 'Tue', value: 2},
{label: 'Wed', value: 3},
{label: 'Thu', value: 4},
{label: 'Fri', value: 5},
{label: 'Sat', value: 6},
{label: 'Sun', value: 7}
]
```

and want to pre-select three values out of it, then you'll have to provide an array of same type for example

```
selectedDays = [
{label: 'Mon', value: 1},
{label: 'Tue', value: 2}
];
```

and your template would look like this

```
<p-multiSelect  [options]="excludeDays" [(ngModel)]="selectedDays"  defaultLabel="Select a day" optionLabel="label"></p-multiSelect>
```

Having explained that, you'll need to have the exact same array of objects in the **patchValue** method instead of having array of numbers.

```
this.form.patchValue({
... : ....
excludeDays: excludeDays //instead of array of numbers you should have same array of objects.
})
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with 2 way binding ngModel, but for reactive form ngModel is deprecated

Comment: I showed ngModel just for example, in your case in the patchValue you'll have to pass the excludeDays original array (and not an array of numbers)

Comment: Yes got it, you were correct we have to pass the same array as is there for the excludeDays. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
let datafromBackend = [1, 2];

let UpdateSelection = [];
this.excludeDays.forEach((item) => {
  if (datafromBackend.findIndex((x) => x === item.value) > -1) {
    UpdateSelection.push(item);
  }
});

this.profileForm.get('excludeDays').setValue(UpdateSelection);
```